# Representing a list in an xsd schema

Tags: java, c#, xsd

I am trying to create an xsd file and generating a corresponding c# class to populate the model.
I am not getting the Addresses part as a list no matter what I do.

sample:

```
<xs:complexType name="member">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Addresses" type="address" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The corresponding class generated does not have a list. Instead it just shows up as a property.

```
    public partial class member
{
   private string FirstName;
   private address Addresses;
}
```

I have imported this xsd into a tool and the resulting output is also a private member(address) instead of a list of addresses.
Is there some attribute that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command in the directory where the xsd is residing.

```
xsd <filename> /c
```

This would generate the class file within the same directory. you must enclose the class in the relevant namespace though for using it in the solution.